# Subscribing to observables in route guards and its implications

Tags: angular, rxjs6, angular-observable, angular-guards

I have a router guard called `PermissionGuard` which is initiated here

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':company',
    component: CompanyComponent,
    canActivate: [PermissionGuard],
    canActivateChild: [PermissionGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: IndexComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'projects',
        loadChildren: '../projects/projects.module#ProjectsModule'
      },
    ]
  }
];
```

Inside my `PermissionGuard` I subscribe to a `PermissionService` like this:

```
export class PermissionGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  private permissions: Permission[];

  constructor(private permissionService: PermissionService, private router: Router) {
    this.permissionService.permissions$.subscribe(
      (permissions: Permission[]) => {
        this.permissions = permissions;
      }
    );
  }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    this.permissionService.getPermissions(next.paramMap.get('company'));
    return this.permissionService.permissionsFetchDone$
    .pipe(filter(x => x))
    .pipe(
      map(response => {
        if (this.permissions) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/forbidden']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and perform necessary `canActivate` or `canActivateChild` checks based on this data. From adding `console.log()` and emitting new data from `permissions$` inside the children routes I can see that the observable is still active, even though the guard has been "used" and the route is activated. I was then expecting it to disappear when I go to a route outside of `path: ':company'`, however the guard isn't destroyed.

**This brings me to my question:**
Am I doing this correctly? I wish to use a guard to check if the user has any permissions, but at the same time I want to perform the HTTP request for permissions only once (when navigating to `path: ':company'` or any of its children). I'm afraid that if I use guards like this it will in time slow down the entire application due to massive amounts of observers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> emitting new data from permissions$ inside the children routes I can see that the observable is still active, even though the guard has been "used" and the route is activated.

First of all, `permissions$` is still active because you never unsubscribed in your guard. And angular creates the guard as singleton.

Even if the guard were not a singleton, the guard's instance is still referenced in the subscription via `this.permissions`, and if your observable exists as variable in your auth service (which I assume is a singleton) this binding would also prevent garbage collection.

> This brings me to my question: Am I doing this correctly? I wish to use a guard to check if the user has any permissions,

It is fine totally fine to issue a request in your guard e.g. for getting permissions.

> but at the same time I want to perform the HTTP request for permissions only once (when navigating to path: ':company' or any of its children).

If you only want to issue the request once then you should think about using [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/multicasting/sharereplay.html) in your auth service so all future instances that connect use the same previously emitted values.

Comment: I only want it to be issued once per `:company` id and its navigation in the children routes, aka. when the company changes, a new http request is required. However, I was mostly concerned about the amount of observables that would appear, however, as guards are singletons I dont see any other option to be honest. Or does angular guards have a version of ngAfterActivation where I can unsubscribe?

Comment: the guard's `can` will be called everytime when you navigate in routes for which the guard is registered (e.g. `:company`), therefore you could subscribe in your `can` method and not store your result in `this.permissions` and then unsubscribe (you only need to unsubscribe though if your observable is held as variable in your auth service though).

Comment: "Or does angular guards have a version of ngAfterActivation where I can unsubscribe?" not really;  you could use the `CanDeactivate` interface but this is actually for deciding if a route can be deactivated, not for unsubscribing.